# Search Exact on WordPress - Relevannsi Solution Not Working

Tags: wp-query, search, pre-get-posts

I have read a lot of articles about exact keyword query problems in WordPress and how to fix them, even though I have followed them but still no success. My website is under construction about software coupons. There is a store named ASTER => https://fantabulouscoupon.com/store/aster-coupon-codes/

I want to search ASTER but when using the default WordPress search it always returns the first result: " MASTER " " BLASTER" even " EASTER " or " FASTER ".

I went to Relevannsi plugin - a powerful custom search plugin but once setup and installed all queries were not working. I think it will be a 2 class query - layer 1 looks for the exact keyword if there isn't one, layer 2 will do the search and return the related keyword. Can someone help me fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: This is something you will need to discuss with Relevanssi support, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: I think someone will know this and intervene directly in the code instead of a 3rd party plugin.